# Why does DTExecUI.exe run fine but DTExec.exe gives me an error?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dtexec

When I try to execute an SSIS package with DTExec.exe with a batch file or in the command prompt it gives me error code 0xC0040019 Data Flow Task 1 (SSIS.Pipeline) data flow objects cannot be loaded. Check if Microsoft.Sqlserver.pipelinexml.dll is properly registered.

I tried storing the SSIS package in the server and in the file system but get the same error. The strange part is when I try to execute the package from DTExecUI.exe it runs without any problems. I tried generating the command line in DTExecUI.exe and using that in the batch file but I still get an error.

I did notice that my server is 64bit and DTExec.exe and DTExecUS.exe are both 32bit versions. I don't know if this is the problem but if so why would one work and the other fail?

Comment: is there a good cause, why you missing qeiting alsi the error message?

Comment: You likely have 32 and 64 bit variants of dtexec and quite possibly more than one version of it on your machine. From a command prompt `where dtexec.exe` If you would please click the edit button and post the entirety of your dtexec call and the full output from the screen. If you don't supply a `/REP` parameter to your call, please use `/REP IEW` so we can see any errors, warnings or information messages.

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I'm experiencing the same issue now. Confirmed the same version of DTSWizard was used to create a package yet DTExecUI works, and DTExec doesn't